# Why are floating points a better for physicists than integers and precision decimals for dealing with large and small numbers?

Tags: floating-point, computer-science

I've been reading up about floating points, to see what they are, and a website said this.

> A physicist needs to use the speed of light (about 300000000) and Newton’s gravitational constant (about 0.0000000000667) together in the same calculation.
>   To satisfy the engineer and the chip designer, a number format has to provide accuracy for numbers at very different magnitudes. However, only relative accuracy is needed. To satisfy the physicist, it must be possible to do calculations that involve numbers with different magnitudes.
>
> Basically, having a fixed number of integer and fractional digits is not useful - and the solution is a format with a floating point.
>
> http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/

I have two problem with the second paragraph.

1. For my web app that is dealing with currency/prices, I've been advised to use "decimal" as a column type instead of "float", as I'm dealing with money, because certain sums can result in the wrong answer.
2. If floating points cannot get `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` right (it calculates as 7, not 8 due to a rounding error* [[source]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)), how can it be suitable for numbers which range from very high to very low (like in the quote above about physicists), considering that it cannot calculate correct answers with numbers that range from `0.1 - 8` in the prev example.

Why do physicists use floating points for their calculations, why not precision decimals like everyone else? I was told not to use them for money, so why use them for science

Also, if calculating `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` or `0.1 + 0.2` *(that equals 0.30000000000000004)* is so hard, but not for integers, why can't computers just calculate the sum without the decimal point `((01 + 07) * 10)` or `01 + 02`, and then put it back in the answer afterwards (add a decimal point 1 digit left from south)? I know a 17 year old who is younger than me who is making a programming language that compiles into javascript. Why couldn't programmers think of removing the decimal point from sums (if arithmetic with small or minus numbers is so hard to calculate), and then putting the decimal point back in the final answer? Thanks to their major blunders, `0.15 + 0.15` and `0.1 + 0.2` can return as false if they are compared against each other with `==` or `>=`. This is absolute madness!

*7.9999999999999991118....

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is very quick. Some calculations require distribution and renting of expensive hardware. If I can speed up a calculation by a factor of 10 then I've saved 90% of the cost. As for precision errors: a 10e-15 error is rather like complaining that you're out by 1mm when computing the distance from Earth to Pluto.

Comment: Yes I know it's faster, but think carefully about what I'm saying. If floating points cannot calculate `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` correctly, which only multiplies two numbers with 1 digit after the decimal point, how can physicists possibly use it with EVEN smaller numbers like 0.0000000000667? This makes no sense! And @Bathsheba, `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` being calculated as 8 instead of 7 is **NOT** a 10e-15 error or discrepancy. It's much bigger.

Comment: A physicist who wrote `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` would be sent back on a programming course.

Comment: Why? I can do it with integers if I removed the decimal point, why not with floats? Why should I have to adapt how I code things, because programmers were too lazy and stupid to think of removing the decimal point (if small numbers are so hard to calculate), and then putting it back after the arithmetic is done?

Comment: You are not required to adapt how you code anything. If you want numbers that are simple when expressed in base 10 to be represented exactly, use a high-level language with a Decimal type, and take advantage of that type.

Comment: **Every** number representation format and arithmetic is a compromise, because it is not possible to represent and do exact arithmetic on general real numbers. You pick the features that matter for a given calculation, and select a number representation based on that. It happens that binary floating point is the best available compromise for many scientific and engineering calculations, where there is nothing special about base 10, important inputs have measurement error before the calculation starts, and both space and time efficiency matters.

Comment: You seem to attach great importance to `floor`. What do you feel are its main uses in scientific and engineering programs?

Answer (score 6):

Base 10 is recommended for financial computations because financial computations are subject to their own standards ([example](http://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/publications/publication1224_en.pdf)), that define the “correct” results in terms of base-10 computations. It would be difficult to simulate the correct computation using base-2 floating-point computation just because it does not naturally match the base-10 language of the financial standards.

Physics does not have base-10 human standards to obey (physics does not have 10 fingers), so any base is as good as the other. You point out one example where base 2 goes bad, `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)`, but it is equally easy to make base 10 go bad: `floor(10 / 3 * 3) = 9` when computed in decimal at any precision.

In fact, the problem with any computation involving `floor` is that `floor` is unstable: a small error in the argument can result in a large error in the result. If you avoid unstable computations, then one base should be as good as the other for your implementation. And binary has several advantages when implemented with logic circuits.

> 0.15 + 0.15 and 0.1 + 0.2

There are infinitely many rational numbers between 0 and 1. Of these, you clearly expect 0.15, 0.1 and 0.2 and their sums to be expressed exactly. If you have these expectations, then base 10 is for you. Physicists do not have any reason to favor these numbers: they use **π**, **G**, other constants I do not know about. Physicists are used not to be able to represent their constants exactly anyway even when one of the constants happens to be 0.1. Physicists have no particular preference for numbers with short decimal expansions over all the other rationals between 0 and 1, the overwhelming majority of which will not be expressed exactly anyway by a trivial counting argument.

Comment: When physicists calculate pi (π) and other cosmological constants and numbers, do they do it in base 10, base 2, or both? Are the numbers interchangeable between different bases? Do physicists do all their calculations in base 2, not just because the universe doesn't have 10 fingers, but because it's much faster on supercomputers and rented cloud servers?

Comment: Physicists use base-2 for all computations ever since they moved from pocket calculators (that use base 10 for technical reasons) to computers. They write `3.14159265358979323846264` and the computer knows that they mean the binary floating-point number closest to π. Actually, it works the same for 1/10: the programmer writes `0.1` and the computer knows that the programmer means the binary floating-point number closest to 1/10. The rules are very simple and work very well. But if don't like these rules, as I said, some high-level languages offer a Decimal type with variants of the same rules.

Comment: The example you gave about base 10 going bad is to do with division, so obviously there would be a remainder. Do you have any examples of base 10 going bad that only consist of addition and multiplication, like the one I gave?

Comment: @desbest In your `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` example, addition and multiplication are working fine. It's the conversion from the decimal representations `0.1` and `0.7` to binary that is the root cause of what you consider as a problem. Instead of `10 / 3` in my example, use “the closest decimal approximation to 10 / 3”, which is a constant and not a division. What? You cannot represent that constant? You are beginning to see the problem then.

Comment: @desbest Some languages have built in constants that represent e.g. the closest 64-bit binary floating point to the exact value of pi.

Comment: @desbest Any decimal number with non-zero digits after the decimal point involves division. `0.7` is defined as `7/10`.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with numbers (and dates!) it is very important to use the right tool for each job. You have to consider at least:

1. Accuracy (difference between real result and calculated result)
2. Numerical stability (margin of error that is induced by each further calculation step)
3. Speed (time you need to wait for the calculation to finish / number of calculation that can be done in a certain time span)

In basic financial calculations you deal with things that can be counted: On the very basic level you deal with whole pennies. This is different when making advanced calculations, e.g. when dealing with investments with compound interests or calculating insurances with probabilities.

When working with fractions, you get the problem that systems using digits cannot represent most fractions with only a finit amount of digits. The binary system can only represent fractions that can be composed from 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 and so on (e.g. 3/8 = 1/4 + 1/8 can be expressed, while 1/10 cannot). The decimal system is a little bit better. It can express much more fractions exactly than the binary system. Still it struggles with simple fractions like 1/3.

If you want to express fractions exactly, you have to express them as fractions. This means you have to calculate the numerator and the denominator separately. Only then you get accurate and stable results. But calculations will be dog slow. In fact, computer algebra systems like Mathematica and Maple provide exactly this mode as an option.

When the problem domain is well understood, one can gain a lot of speed by using certain shortcuts. One shortcut is to throw out accuracy and work with an approximate result. When doing this, it is very important to order the partial calculations in a way the preserve the required numerical stability. A very simple example: `1/sqrt(x)` is less accurate than `sqrt(x)/x`. Doing this optimizations requires a rigor mathematical analysis. Otherwise the results will not only be inaccurate, but plain wrong.

A physicist can use inexact floating point operations, when she analyzed the impact on accuracy and when she has coded her algorithm in a way that preserves the required numerical stability. Same holds true when doing advanced financial calculations. In fact, trading companies hire mathematicians and physicists for building trading algorithms. But people being able to do such analysis are very rare. So for most simple financial calculations, people are told to simply calculate in whole pennies.

Comment: The “much more fractions” in your answer can be misleading. When you have 64 bits to allocate to the representation of a fractional number, you are going to get 2^64 exact fractions or a bit less. In fact, IEEE 754's decimal64 wastes considerably more bit patterns than IEEE 754's binary64. The sentence “The decimal system is a little bit better” is only true in principle outside of any specific format with a finite quantity of information allocated to it (and it doesn't help that information is measured and stored in bits either).

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: I am not writing about a specific representation. Binary can represent 1/2 etc, while decimal can encode 1/2, 1/5 and 1/10 etc.

Comment: @stefan: the big problem is that most decimals only have a small exponent range. They are pretty accurate inside that range (which should be extremely well fitted for financial calculations, as it is still a lot higher than all the money on earth, no matter in what valuta), but nothing is possible outside. IEEE FP can deal with values well below and well above the range most decimals have. And a physicist will not use floor anyway. He would leave the results as they are, which would be very CLOSE to 8, but probably slightly below it.

Comment: FWIW, calcualting in whole pennies won't always cut it, since there may be percentages (like 1.75%) to calculate too, but counting in fixed format is probably good enough, and otherwise, say, an 128 bit decimal floating point number (like Decimal, in .NET) would cover everything a banker mightr eve need, and some more.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis IEEE FP are good on the speed side, but not so good on accuracy. Variable length BCD will be more accurate (although much slower). A 128 bit number will be quite accurate but very slow (especially when you want to use vectoring functions, e.g. the ones on your graphic card). This won't impact most bankers, but it might be a serious problem for bankers doing algorithmic trading. So in fact you will always need a careful analysis.

Comment: @stefan: I know. I merely wanted to stress (actually to the OP more than to you) why decimal is best suited for financial stuff, but not for scientific calculations. Of course, if speed and memory were  irrelevant, one could use something like BigDecimal or some such. FWIW, a scientist would rather round() -- to 8 -- than use floor().

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended comment, rather than an answer.

I would like to give the OP a simple challenge, and an opportunity to demonstrate the feasibility and effectiveness of "removing the decimal point from sums (if arithmetic with small or minus numbers is so hard to calculate), and then putting the decimal point back in the final answer" for scientific and engineering programming. This is, of course, exactly what decimal number systems such as Java's BigDecimal do, with the software keeping track of the decimal point location.

Many scientific and engineering programs involve solving systems of linear equations. Many more involve similar linear algebra manipulations. As a result, linear equation solution is a common form of benchmark for scientific computation.

[LINPACK 1000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK_benchmarks#LINPACK_1000) measures how fast a system solves a system of 1000 linear equations. It permits changes to the solver, so the OP could write an implementation that does not use binary floating point inside the solver, and obtain valid results. Source code is available in several languages to provide a starting point. I suggest aiming for at least the accuracy that is routinely achieved using IEEE 64-bit binary floating point. The input is supplied in binary floating point format, but every binary floating point number has an exact decimal representation.

Results are published for many systems - see various papers by Jack Dongarra, such as the 2013 paper [Performance of Various Computers Using Standard Linear Equations Software](ftp://ftp.irisa.fr/pub/netlib/benchmark/performance.pdf). There should be no difficulty comparing the OP's results for both accuracy and performance to results from comparable hardware using binary floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to throw in my two cents:

- Most computers today do calculations in binary format because it's easy to build in hardware and doesn't matter as long as integers are used. A notable exception are IBM zSeries (and probably iSeries) that have builtin support for binary coded decimals (BCD).
- The trouble when using `float`-variables for monetary values isn't because of using floating-point-notation but because they use **binary** floating-point-variables which don't map well to **exact** decimal values.
- COBOL and PL/I (especially on zSeries) offer decimal fixed point variables that are great for managing amounts of currencies - and they do just what you said: they remember the position of the decimal point and all arithmetic operations are a mix of integer operations and rotating the digits around to move position of the decimal point.
- Then why do physicist use such inaccurate things like binary float variables? Since most of the values they handle aren't accurate from the beginning. Each value that results from a measurement carries some error, so the additional "fuzziness" that comes from doing floating point calculations doesn't really matter. `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` doesn't make sense or could as well result in `7` when `0.1` actually is `0.1 +- 10%` and `0.7` is `0.7 +- 5%`.